# Смена размера изображения через PIL

Tags: python, python-3.x, pillow

Есть у меня такой код

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('temp.jpg')
im.resize((im.width//10,im.height//10))
im.show()
im.save('temp1.jpg')
```

Сделан он, что бы сильно уменьшать картинку, мне не важно качество и тд. Но оно сохраняет ту же самую картинку

Answer (score 2):

Метод [Image.resize](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize) создаёт и возвращает копию изображения с изменённым размером, не меняя исходное изображение.

```
im = im.resize((im.width//10,im.height//10))
```